# Locating files and displaying their owner

Tags: linux, centos, find, locate

I have to search for a specific file type on a storage unit and also want to know their owners.

With `locate '*.txt' >> result.txt` I find all files I'm looking for but I'm missing the owner this way.

Any suggestions on how I could do it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
locate -0 '*.txt' | xargs -r0 stat -c "%n %U" >>result.txt
```

should do the trick

Comment: Note using `locate` in this manner returns files that contain `.txt` anywhere in their names. For example: `...nginx/deployment_example.txt.erb`.

Comment: @slm, in the original question, there was `*.txt` (without the quotes), but the `*` was hidden because of SE formatting, so the question showed `.txt`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas The leading `*` has no effect since locate assumes a leading and trailing `*` on the pattern.

Comment: @DougO'Neal no, `locate` assumes a leading and trailing `*` only if there's no wildcard character in the search string. So `locate .txt` is like `locate '*.txt*'` while `locate '*.txt'` **is** `locate '*.txt'`

Answer (score 4):

locate will work as long as the directory is indexed. Otherwise use find

```
find /directory/to/search -name "*.txt" -exec ls -ld {} + >> result.txt
```

Comment: With indexed you mean visible ?Like the result when using `ls` ?

Comment: No, the command "locate" uses a database to track files. The database is updated daily. You can manually update it with the command `sudo updatedb`, but the database does not include all system files and may not include removable devices depending on how you configured locate and if the device was connected when the database was last updated. See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/locate-command-examples/

Comment: Note that some `find` implementation have a `-ls` option to avoid executing `ls`. GNU `find` also has a `-printf` to output specific information like owner and path.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to handle file names with newlines and special characters in them, you'll want to output the user name first (since it can't contain special characters) and a NUL-separated list:

```
locate -0 .txt | xargs -r0 stat --printf "%U %n\0"
```

You can then process the files [reliably](https://superuser.com/a/397134/2259):

```
while IFS=: read -r -d '' -u 9 user path
do
    whatever_you_want -- "$path"
done 9< <( locate -0 .txt | xargs -r0 stat --printf "%U:%n\0" )
```

The advantage over [@DougONeal's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108405/3645) is that it's easy to parse the result since the simple user name is first in the string, and since paths with newlines are handled correctly.

Comment: Don't you need to set `$REPLY` somewhere? And what is `command` doing there? As  far as I can tell, it is attempting to run the `$path`, shouldn't that be an `echo` or `printf`?

Comment: `REPLY` is the default name for each "line" if you don't specify a name.

Comment: Ah, thanks, did not know about REPLY and thought that you meant the builtin `command`.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly only want files that end in the suffix `.txt` the accepted answer will not do that. It will return results like this for example:

```
$ locate -0 .txt | xargs -r0 stat -c "%n %U" | grep -Ev '.txt '
...
/home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/templates/apache2/run_installer_as_root.txt.erb saml
/home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/templates/apache2/welcome.txt.erb saml
/home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/templates/nginx/ask_for_extra_configure_flags.txt.erb saml
/home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/templates/nginx/cannot_write_to_dir.txt.erb saml
/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/usr_42.txt.gz root
...
```

Instead you can tell `locate` to use a regex instead like so:

```
$ locate -0 --regex '\.txt$' | xargs -r0 stat -c "%n %U"
```

Comment: @sim If you set the regex flag then you'll also have to escape the . in .txt - otherwise it will match any character.  Files such as /usr/bin/ps2txt will show up.